# New VPS unreachable from some points

Tags: domain-name-system, vps

first of all, im new to this VPS thing, and i have a Centos VPS at contabo.com.

I setup a webserver and started hosting a website.

I tried to setup a dns server too with bind, but could not make it work, so i am using the freedns.afraid.org.

The website and vps ip is being reachable from my dsl home computer, but when i tried to access the website using my 4G tablet, it cannot find the website.

So i did some testing, and noticed that it is not being reachable from some points, as you can check here:

watchmouse.com

and type my domain dvdplaza.org or ip 193.37.152.191

Must locations gives 100% packet error.

Packets are lost either by pinging the VPS IP as pinging the domain (dvdplaza.org).

downforeveryoneorjustme.com/dvdplaza.org

Is it a issue with the VPS provider?

Is it a issue with my server configuration?

Is it a issue with the freedns.afraid.org?

I asked the vps provider, they said thay was going to check it, but it still the same.

**Is my website reachable for you?** (answer that pls just for checking)

Can someone please help me to debug it?

Thank you.

EDIT: i also have a postfix+dovecot mail server on the same VPS and inbound and outbound mailing works with no error. MX mail.dvdplaza.org

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-b.google.com tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-b.google.com udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-a.google.com tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-a.google.com udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-a.google.com tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             google-public-dns-a.google.com udp spt:domain
LOCALOUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:domain
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
INVALID    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpts:tcpmux:65535
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpts:tcpmux:65535
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp destination-unreachable
LOGDROPOUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ALLOWIN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  bd650748.virtua.com.br  anywhere

Chain ALLOWOUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             bd650748.virtua.com.br

Chain DENYIN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  177.3.146.160        anywhere
DROP       all  --  193.227.34.49        anywhere
DROP       all  --  dhcp-089-099-208-212.chello.nl  anywhere
DROP       all  --  14.63.224.220        anywhere
DROP       all  --  220.182.3.163        anywhere
DROP       all  --  110.172.52.34        anywhere
DROP       all  --  28.114.191.90.dyn.estpak.ee  anywhere
DROP       all  --  219.144.17.74        anywhere
DROP       all  --  192.151.145.42       anywhere
DROP       all  --  rrcs-70-60-185-231.central.biz.rr.com  anywhere
DROP       all  --  201-69-30-191.dial-up.telesp.net.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  117.79.148.54        anywhere
DROP       all  --  162-17-233-89-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net  anywhere     
DROP       all  --  mx.busap.com         anywhere
DROP       all  --  101.162.176.243      anywhere
DROP       all  --  CPE-121-216-59-226.lnse1.ken.bigpond.net.au  anywhere      
DROP       all  --  c-97f670d5.03-77-67626721.cust.bredbandsbolaget.se  anywhere
DROP       all  --  189-30-99-230.ccoce700.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br  anywhere  
DROP       all  --  177.125.246.32       anywhere
DROP       all  --  187-123-108-35.cpeoco.viaembratel.net.br  anywhere         
DROP       all  --  b3d86532.virtua.com.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  5.199.133.110        anywhere
DROP       all  --  220.178.18.67        anywhere
DROP       all  --  1112.globatel.ru     anywhere
DROP       all  --  ip187-86-17-197.anid.com.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  crawl-66-249-78-47.googlebot.com  anywhere
DROP       all  --  61.155.177.58        anywhere
DROP       all  --  219.138.203.198      anywhere
DROP       all  --  bb27efd9.virtua.com.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  mx.iniap.gob.ec      anywhere
DROP       all  --  95.141.28.77         anywhere
DROP       all  --  94.156.12.144        anywhere
DROP       all  --  114.80.224.90        anywhere
DROP       all  --  88-190-35-168.rev.dedibox.fr  anywhere
DROP       all  --  200-153-231-253.dsl.telesp.net.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  host162-198-static.205-37-b.business.telecomitalia.it  anywhere
DROP       all  --  183.203.16.231       anywhere
DROP       all  --  host01.dbxmedia.com  anywhere
DROP       all  --  bade8fd6.virtua.com.br  anywhere
DROP       all  --  80.87.72.10          anywhere
DROP       all  --  2.25.198.76          anywhere
DROP       all  --  gateway.vikingserv.net  anywhere
DROP       all  --  253.233.15.37.dynamic.jazztel.es  anywhere
DROP       all  --  061093207014.ctinets.com  anywhere
DROP       all  --  200.195.70.4         anywhere

Chain DENYOUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             177.3.146.160
DROP       all  --  anywhere             193.227.34.49
DROP       all  --  anywhere             dhcp-089-099-208-212.chello.nl
DROP       all  --  anywhere             14.63.224.220
DROP       all  --  anywhere             220.182.3.163
DROP       all  --  anywhere             110.172.52.34
DROP       all  --  anywhere             28.114.191.90.dyn.estpak.ee
DROP       all  --  anywhere             219.144.17.74
DROP       all  --  anywhere             192.151.145.42
DROP       all  --  anywhere             rrcs-70-60-185-231.central.biz.rr.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             201-69-30-191.dial-up.telesp.net.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             117.79.148.54
DROP       all  --  anywhere             162-17-233-89-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
DROP       all  --  anywhere             mx.busap.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             101.162.176.243
DROP       all  --  anywhere             CPE-121-216-59-226.lnse1.ken.bigpond.net.au
DROP       all  --  anywhere             c-97f670d5.03-77-67626721.cust.bredbandsbolaget.se
DROP       all  --  anywhere             189-30-99-230.ccoce700.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             177.125.246.32
DROP       all  --  anywhere             187-123-108-35.cpeoco.viaembratel.net.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             b3d86532.virtua.com.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             5.199.133.110
DROP       all  --  anywhere             220.178.18.67
DROP       all  --  anywhere             1112.globatel.ru
DROP       all  --  anywhere             ip187-86-17-197.anid.com.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             crawl-66-249-78-47.googlebot.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             61.155.177.58
DROP       all  --  anywhere             219.138.203.198
DROP       all  --  anywhere             bb27efd9.virtua.com.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             mx.iniap.gob.ec
DROP       all  --  anywhere             95.141.28.77
DROP       all  --  anywhere             94.156.12.144
DROP       all  --  anywhere             114.80.224.90
DROP       all  --  anywhere             88-190-35-168.rev.dedibox.fr
DROP       all  --  anywhere             200-153-231-253.dsl.telesp.net.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             host162-198-static.205-37-b.business.telecomitalia.it
DROP       all  --  anywhere             183.203.16.231
DROP       all  --  anywhere             host01.dbxmedia.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             bade8fd6.virtua.com.br
DROP       all  --  anywhere             80.87.72.10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             061093207014.ctinets.com
DROP       all  --  anywhere             200.195.70.4

Chain INVALID (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
INVDROP    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN/FIN,SYN
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN,RST
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,RST/FIN,RST
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,ACK/FIN
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:PSH,ACK/PSH
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:ACK,URG/URG
INVDROP    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW

Chain INVDROP (10 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOCALINPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ALLOWIN    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DENYIN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOCALOUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ALLOWOUT   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DENYOUT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGDROPIN (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootpc
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootpc
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:sunrpc
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sunrpc
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:auth
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:auth
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:epmap:netbios-ssn
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:epmap:netbios-ssn
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:microsoft-ds
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:isakmp
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:isakmp
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:login
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:who
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:efs
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:router
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* '
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* '
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGDROPOUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning uid prefix `Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* '
LOG        udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning uid prefix `Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* '
LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 30/min burst 5 LOG level warning uid prefix `Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: if you're having issues even using just the IP address, you can take DNS out of the equation for the cause.

Comment: @emynd Do you think it is a problem with the vps provider? is my website dvdplaza.org reachable to you?

Comment: isup.me/dvdplaza.org shows it as down, as does me trying to connect. I get ping responses and port 80 (normally http) is opened and accepting connections (telnet connected). however, it seems like it's not taking http requests. make sure the process using said port is the web service and not another service.

Comment: thats strange.. i can reach the website using my home computer, but no one can?

Comment: you can check if your server is reachable from several locations with http://just-ping.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It looks like there could be some kind of issue with your DNS provider, according to a quick [DNS propagation check](http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/dvdplaza.org).</s>

My advice would be to investigate this with your provider and raise a support ticket. If the issue persists, perhaps investigate using a different provider (most domain registrars give you at least basic DNS functionality).

I spoke too soon, it seems the check also fails on the same servers for my own domains, so DNS propagation may not be the problem.

Can you check your web-server logs (you haven't mentioned what web server you're using) to verify that the connections are reaching the server? You can also try running a packet capture using `tcpdump`, though your VPS provider may prohibit this.

Does pinging your IP work from your home network (FWIW, I can ping the IP with no problems, with consistent response times of around 130-140ms from the UK)?

Some more debugging details, it appears port 80 is closed:

```
root@deploy-01:~# nmap -A dvdplaza.org

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-07-11 21:31 CEST
Nmap scan report for dvdplaza.org (193.37.152.191)
Host is up (0.011s latency).
rDNS record for 193.37.152.191: ip-191-152-37-193.static.contabo.net
Not shown: 969 filtered ports, 28 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp   open  ftp     vsftpd 2.2.2
|_ftp-bounce: no banner
22/tcp   open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.3 (protocol 2.0)
9091/tcp open  http    Transmission BitTorrent management httpd (unauthorized)
```

Can you verify your web-server is running? Try `netstat -anp | grep 80` (also try grepping for 'httpd', 'apache').

Comment: I actually figured that iptables is blocking http conections, when i stop iptables service, the website becomes reachable. The strange thing is that after some minutes, iptables looks to auto enable itself, and website becomes unreachable again.

Comment: You can add an iptables rule to allow port 80: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-11-how-to-block-or-open-httpweb-service.html

Also, try posting the output of `iptables -L` to your original post so we can see your firewall setup.

Comment: ok, done. the rules list was so big i couldnt capture it all in terminal. What all that means?

Comment: Have you tried adding the iptables rule for port 80? Your iptables configuration looks pretty complex - did you add all the rules manually, or have they been added for you?

Comment: i never added anything manually. im so surprised as you.. i really dont understand. how can i clean it and make it more basic and directed to a webserver/mailserver/ftp/etc..?

Comment: You can flush all of your rules using a script here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-how-to-flush-all-rules.html - then run `/etc/init.d/iptables save` to save the changes so that they persist. Once you have a flushed rules list, re-add your rules for port 21, 22, 25, 80, etc. and keep an eye on the list to see if you have anything adding rules for you.